# What is the best solution in order to communicate browser and xamarin app on LAN?

Tags: javascript, html, xamarin, browser, xamarin.forms

I have a project curious. I have to Exchange information between Xamarin app and a browser on other device. The website is served by app with http server. This communication has various requirements:

- It has to work without internet, for example, on ad-hoc Wi-Fi network.
- App can be turned off during a time.
- App has to send new information to browser when user change something on app
- Website has to be html5+javascript. It can’t have flash, applet java… because the browser can be a phone, tablet, pc…

I have searched and there is available http server for browser (https://github.com/mafintosh/browser-server) but I haven’t been able to call it from other device. Other solution is websockets, doing a polling with get/post from browser (this is worse than websockets).

So my questions are: do you know some tool that I can develop an http server on browser? If I can’t do it, are there other solution that are different of doing get call each 10 seconds?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually websocket is what you want.

Simply client side, have a changelog, for when the server is offline, log all changes client side, and when the server is back up and you get back your websocket connection, send all the changes to the server.